# Windows 7 freezes on startup after Windows update - setting up personalized settings for internet explorer

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, freeze, boot

Got a Windows update that prompted automatic restart, on restart every time I try to log on get a black screen with a "Setting up personalized settings for: Internet explorer" message. It can still boot up fine in safe mode.

Does anyone have any insight on how to solve this?

Comment: Any events in te Windows logs?  How long have you left it at the screen?

Comment: Any other details? It's hard to have insight on a generic message if we have no (trace) logs at our disposal...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be due to a permission issue, just boot once with that user as an `administrator` instead of a `standard user`, then set his account type back. Here is the topic where I found that:

> I also had the same problem with Windows7 Home and I attempted the safe mode method but I still have the have issue with the new user account. I altered the user from Standard to Administrator as well as immediately had a successful login. I after that altered the user back to Standard. Thank you all of you for your valuable suggestion.
>
> — [Re: Windows 7 stops at “Setting up personalized settings for: Browser Customization”
>    #5](http://forums.techarena.in/operating-systems/1384978.htm#post5166893)

If that doesn't work, you can try a repair:

> 1. Insert the Windows 7 DVD
> 2. Restart your computer
> 3. When asked if you want to boot from your DVD drive, do so.
> 4. Choose your language, click Next.
> 5. Click 'Repair your computer'
> 6. Select operating system you want repair
>
> — [Windows 7 update freezes at loading personalized settings?](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100429105410AA9ejtp)

If that doesn't work, you can remove the offending update (KB might differ for you, read through them):

> 1. Hold down the power button for 10-15 seconds to shutdown without hibernating.
> 2. Restart system with the power button and boot into Safe Mode and logon.
> 3. Type "Windows Update" into the Start Menu search box and choose View Installed Updates under Control Panel.
> 4. Choose "Update for Microsoft Windows (KB980408)" and then choose uninstall.
> 5. Confirm that you want to uninstall and reboot when requested.
> 6. Start normally and you should be good.
>
> — [Windows 7 update freezes at loading personalized settings?](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100429105410AA9ejtp)